# Django Looking for URLS of a Different Project

Tags: python, django

I have two projects in django that I´m working on at the same time. Today something really strange happened after switching projects.

I have my first project: urls.py and manage.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'agenda.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^agenda/', include('modulo_agenda.urls')),
    url(r'^schedule/', include('schedule.urls')),

)


"""
Django settings for agenda project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."),
)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@7j23xm3jv=(#gicejabv2ppa$063st+d@)2x^thld0(#!chwq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'modulo_agenda',
    'schedule',
  'djangobower',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'agenda.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'agenda.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "site_media")
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (


"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.request",

)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)
BOWER_PATH = 'C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages'
BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "components")
BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap'
)
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 1 # Monday
ROOT_URLCONF = 'agenda.urls'
```

And my second project settings and urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'proyecto_final_web.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^music/', include('music_manager.urls')),
)



"""
Django settings for proyecto_final_web project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=%65sc*)pue#)wj&pxd#meh3s_v(^s***+ns(p*8_@pjla_+xo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'proyecto_final_web.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'proyecto_final_web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_PATH=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (TEMPLATE_PATH,)
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

The problem I´m having is that when I type run server I get on my agenda project I get:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 30, 2015 - 13:33:04
Django version 1.7, using settings 'agenda.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

It´s saying it is using agenda.settings, which has `ROOT_URLCONF = 'agenda.urls'`

But when trying to go to the URL localhots:8000/schedule I get this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in proyecto_final_web.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^music/
The current URL, schedule/, didn't match any of these.
```

Which are the URLS defined in my other project. I don´t understand why this happens since on the runserver it is saying it´s using the agenda.settings and not the proyecto_final_web.settings.

Can anyone tell me what might be happening?

Comment: Maybe you can try clearing all the `.pyc` files in your project and run again if that helps.

Comment: Also check if value of `PROJECT_ROOT` has been defined correctly.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I did not have the PROJECT_ROOT on one of my projects. This solved the issue. Can you post the answer so I can upvote it and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code above, there seems to be error in `PROJECT_ROOT` settings. One project has `PROJECT_ROOT` setting defined and other project does not seem to have this setting.

You need to ensure that `PROJECT_ROOT` has been defined correctly and for both the projects.